# check if div has overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to check if a `<div>` has overflow and show a link if it does. I have three divs with same classes. I want to check each div for overflow and show or hide link. This is my html:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-panel active" >
  <div>
    LETO 2015: ALNJA
    <br>
    <br>
    Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
  </div>
  <a id="morelink">more</a>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-panel">
  <div>
    Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
  </div>
  <a id="morelink">more</a>
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-panel">
  <div>
    Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
  </div>
  <a id="morelink">more</a>
</div>`
```

css:

```
  .tab-panel {
   position:relative;
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
   color: #000;
   height: 276px;
   line-height: 20px;
   padding:20px;
  }
 .tab-panel div {overflow: hidden;height: 100%;}
```

Comment: By "overflow," are you trying to determine if a `div` takes up multiple lines?

Comment: no. i need to see if it is overflowing. in my case div with id=tab-1 is overflowing, the html above is just sample it has much more lines in each div.

Comment: i can upload my css if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I understand your question, but someone else may be able to help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**: I made several updates to this answer. The original one didn't meet the needs of the OP because not all the *div* elements where visible at the same time (see comments). I will first answer the general question: "*how to check if a div is overflowed?*" and then address the OP problem.

**NOTE**: I have modified the original *html* and *css* to make the example clear.

---

So we have a container (a *div* element) that we call 'tab'. It has other *div* inside that we call 'content'. If 'content' is bigger than 'tab', then 'tab' is overflowed.

The key is to compare [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) attributes of 'content'.

If `scrollHeight` is bigger than `clientHeight`, we change the `display` property of the link to make it visible. We use the *id* selector to identify 'content'.

HTML:

```
<div id="tab"> <div id="content">...</div> </div>
```

JS:

```
if ($('#content').prop('scrollHeight') > $('#content').prop('clientHeight'))
    //if 'true', the content overflows the tab: we show the hidden link
    $('#myLink').css('display', 'block');
}
```

### What happens if we have more than one 'tab'?

In that case we need to use the `each` function to wrap the code above and iterate the different 'tabs':

HTML:

```
<div class="tab"> <div class="content">...</div> </div>
<div class="tab"> <div class="content">...</div> </div>
...
```

JS:

```
$('.tab').each( function() {
    if ($('.content', this).prop('scrollHeight') > $('.content', this).prop('clientHeight'))
    $('a', this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Note how we use now *class selectors* and we search the elements in the context of `this`.

### Adressing the OP problem

In this case, just one of the 'tabs' is visible, while the others are hidden until the user raise a event that changes the visibility.

We can not compare the `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` attributes of a hidden element (both will return 0). So we need to make the comparison in the handler of the event that make it visible.

The following snippet manage that situation.

```js
function updateTabs()
{
  $('.tab-panel').each( function() {
    if ($('div', this).prop('scrollHeight') > $('div', this).prop('clientHeight'))
      $('a', this).css('display', 'block');
  });
}

$('span').click( function() {
  $('.tab-panel').removeClass('active');
  $('#'+$(this).data('tab')).addClass('active');
  updateTabs();
});

updateTabs();
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
}

.tab-panel {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 76px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.tab-panel.active {
  display: block;
}

.tab-panel div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.show-more {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</span>
<span data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</span>
<span data-tab="tab-3">Tab 3</span>
<hr>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-panel active">
  <div>
    I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>
  </div>
  <a class="show-more">more</a>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-panel">
  <div>
    I have little text.
    <br>
  </div>
  <a class="show-more">more</a>
</div>

<div id="tab-3" class="tab-panel">
  <div>
    I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>I have a lot of text.
    <br>
  </div>
  <a class="show-more">more</a>
</div>
```

Also, please note that one issue with your code is that all the *links* have the same *id*, `morelink` should be a *class* (or have different names).

Comment: that is what i need,but this code works only for one div in my case. I didn't say that my 3 divs are tab panels. something like this: http://www.javascriptbook.com/code/c11/tabs.html

Comment: Do you mean taht in every `tab-panel` you have more than one _div_ or element? If so, you can put all the contain of your _tabs_ inside one _div_. Then it should work.

Comment: one tab panel one div. like on that link.

Comment: In that link there is one `<p>` element inside each `<div class="tab-panel">`element. Changing `($('div', this)` for `($('p', this)` will make my code to work on that website.

Comment: In case you mean that it is working just for one _tab-panel div_, I have modified the snippet to show how it also works when the third _div_ overflows. If in your case it is not working you should give us more information. The fact that they are tab panels is irrelevant.

Comment: @DejanJankov — the main idea here is to compare `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight`, and David put together a good example of doing that. If it doesn't _exactly_ meet your situation you should be able to adapt it. Don't expect David to complete _your_ work and hand it to you.

Comment: that much i know and i am trying to make it work in my case. its not like i don't appreciate his help.

Comment: You can also mark the answer as correct if it helps you. Btw I modify the snippet, now it is calling the function that iterate the tabs every time you click in the _span_ elements. Likey your issue was that the content was hide, so the comparation dind't happen (so it seems that, after all, it is relevant that they are _tab panels_) @StephenP: thank you for your words.